# What is the best practice for wildcard/prelude imports in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

In Rust, we can import everything from the given module using `use module_name::*;` syntax. While I can see that this results in faster development[1], I like the mantra of Python: "explicit is better than implicit". And while I can certainly see the benefit of implicit `use std::prelude::*;`, I feel uncomfortable with `use diesel::prelude::*;` (well, it is an explicit import, but should it really be a wildcard?).

Is it fine if I go with explicit `use diesel::{RunQueryDsl, ExpressionMethods, QueryDsl};` or should I give up and use `use diesel::prelude::*;`?

[1] you don't need to duplicate all the names you want to import and neither you need to prefix all the items from the module with `module_name::`

Comment: The prelude is meant to be imported by wildcard, but this does not mean you have to use it. However, keep in mind that it often includes traits that are not obviously used but needed to invoke methods on types. (Calling a method whose trait is not in scope causes a compiler error.)